# R POSIXct 0-23 hour format to 1-24

Tags: r, time

What is the best way to change POSIXct 0-23 hour format to 1-24?

> hour+1?

Do I have to redefine the hours (e.g. 0:23 = 1:24)

Comment: then midnight becomes 1am...2 am becomes 3 am...

Answer (score 0):

No. POSIXct does not store values as hours with am/pm designation. You need to use the input and output formats found on the ?strptime page.

Comment: The man page only had 0-23 format hours    

  ‘%H’ Hours as decimal number (00-23).  As a special exception
          times such as ‘24:00:00’ are accepted for input, since ISO
          8601 allows these.

     ‘%I’ Hours as decimal number (01-12).